# Does anyone have any luck with running multiple crate.io nodes on virtualized environment?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, crate

I'm using crate.io to test replication between nodes. I've two instances running on two separate Ubuntu machines running on VirtualBox on the same local network. The instance is not able to recognize additional nodes - seems like each one is running on its own. Does anyone have any experience in configuring multiple nodes?

Answer (score 0):

By default crate nodes are discovering themselves using multicast which seems not to work at your network setup. Switching to unicast should solve this:

> discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
>   discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:
>    - crate1.example.com:4300
>    - crate2.example.com:4300
>    - crate3.example.com:4300

This blog post describes it well: https://crate.io/blog/using-crate-in-multinode-setup.

Comment: Since multi- and broadcast is blocked in AWS environments I guess this will be a solution for AWS too.